# tomcat not starting after myeclipse break

Tags: tomcat, myeclipse

I have always had the following problem. Sometimes, myEclipse is blocked. So I'm obliged to close it via task manager on windows. When I reopen it and want to start tomcat, I have this issue. Tomcat isn't stating and the console shows me this message:

```
only one address use is allowed and tells that the adress is already in use

StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
```

How do I deal with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your tomcat might not stooped, just go to task manager and check there, any instance of javaw or etc still running there that is cause of this error.